# Getting started with Laravel and Sentry

Tags: laravel, cartalyst-sentry

I found a Laravel 4 announcement on HN a few weeks ago and thought I could give it a try.

After looking for a basic tutorial, I found this one:

http://www.codeforest.net/laravel4-simple-website-with-backend-1

And ran into what is probably a silly problem: the command `php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry` created a single table in my database when it should have created four, according to the tutorial.

Is there some step missing, or did I assume wrong when I thought it had something setup to create the needed tables?

Looking at the Sentry home I couldn´t find what I did wrong, so I´ll just look for the SQL to create the tables in the source, but I still would like to know what was the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First run

```
php artisan migrate
```

Then run

```
php artisan migrate --package=cartalyst/sentry
```

After doing this it should create these tables: **migrations, groups, throttle, users, user_groups**

If fails again, destroy your database, re-create and re-run these steps.

Comment: Perfect. Thanks. Also made me realize I missed the equal sign.